# matlab change each char element to cell type in a cell array

Tags: matlab, char, cell-array

I have an array of cells which looks like this

```
result =
  [49x2 char]
  [49x2 char]
  [49x2 char]
  [49x2 char]
  [49x2 char]
  [49x2 char]
```

(the length of result could be really large)
And I want to change each element to cell type. 
like

```
 r = cell{2,1}, r{1} = ['ab';'cd';'rf'], r{2} = ['rt';'cd';'er']
```

to

```
 r = {'ab';'cd';'rf';'rt';'cd';'er'}
```

I have tried to use phrases like cellstr([r{:}]), but it turns out this will change r to

```
r = 
'abab'
'cdcd'
'rfrt'
```

And I know I can use loop like this

```
for i = 1:length(r)
 a = [a ; cellstr(r{i})]
```

But I think it coast too much space. And can anyone help?
Thanks so much.

Comment: can you put a MAT file here? it would be easier and faster

Comment: what? you should just apply cellstr to each row of your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. You need to concatenate the comma-separeted list `r{:}` vertically, not horizontally. So, use

```
cellstr(vertcat(r{:}))
```